# Decorating current_route_match service inexplicably causes fatal errors in webforms (and possibly elsewhere)

Tags: 8, webforms, services

When decorating the current_route_match service I'm seeing issues with various webform requests (either fatal errors or ajax responses making no changes) when navigating past page two of a multi-page form and in some other areas. Based on my debugging this may be more of a general form issue than a webform issue as it seems to be caused by the form display missing from the form storage in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm::getEditedFieldNames(). Disabling caching by altering forms mitigates it but does not completely remove it.

It is the act of decorating the service that causes the problem, not any override of functionality. The issue occurs even if the decorated service *supplies the exact same class*. E.g. the issue will be caused by a module consisting of nothing but an .info.yml file and a services file as follows:

```yaml
services:
  decorator_test.route_match:
    class: Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch
    decorates: current_route_match
    decoration_priority: 0
    public: false
    arguments:
      - '@request_stack'
```

I'm pretty stumped on this. Why would this possibly be happening? Or how could I even go about debugging something like this?

Comment: You set `public: false` why is that? That will make the service* unusable in code, you can only use it as an argument for other services.

Comment: @Beebee It's copied from another more complicated decorator and service, this is a stripped down version for testing/demonstration. The original decorator applies changes to the current_route_match service to be used when that service is available. Switching public to true does not affect the issue.

Comment: @Beebee wait, now it does, at least on my test site. I'm positive that didn't fix it before.

Comment: you need to `cache:rebuild` in between changes to `*.services.yml` files else they won't get picked up most likely. I'm pretty sure setting `public: false` will cause lots of issues since the current route match service is quite heavily used in other modules, not just as a service argument, but in code.

Comment: @Beebee I did. It fixes it on my test site, but not on my actual site. There's some other difference that causes a very similar issue even when public is set to true. I need to investigate a bit more to figure out what.

Comment: @Beebee if you post that as an answer I'll likely accept it or at least upvote it, that does fix it for another full site with the same issue, just not the specific one that started me on this in the first place.

Comment: `public` only affects the new service, not the original one. *... the decorated service supplies the exact same class* - I think this needs more context what you are trying to do. If it is only for debugging purpose try to copy the class to your own namespace.

Comment: @4k4 That was my understanding as well when I first wrote my decorator many a year ago (well, 2 years ago) but Beebee's solution does seem to work for most cases. By "the decorated service supplies the exact same class" I mean exactly as in the example in the question. In the real scenario it doesn't do that (but public: true still works for some sites using it). I will update the question with a better example once I figure out what's actually special about the site it doesn't work with.

Comment: I figured out why this was still broken on the one site. Bit anticlimactic but I had a form alter where caching of the webform was disabled (ironically as a partial workaround for this same issue). That form alter was causing a very similar issue to happen even when the fix that worked for other sites (setting public: true on the decorator) was applied.